# Does EPPlus require Excel to be installed on the sever?

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

Does EPPlus require Excel to be installed on the server ? If yes, are there any better alternatives for exporting bulk data using Entity Framework from server-side code to an excel file?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: I checked, It does not require Excel to be installed on the server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it does not require Excel to be installed on the server, as you can read in the [docs](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus):

> EPPlus is a .NET library that reads and writes Excel files using the Office Open XML format (xlsx). EPPlus has no dependencies other than .NET.

You do need to put the EPPlus assembly on the server though.